# How to compile C/C++ for Windows 32 using MinGW?

Tags: gcc, mingw, gnu, mingw-w64, mingw32

I can compile C/C++ code using MinGW for Windows 64-bit.
But how can I compile C/C++ code using MinGW for Windows 32-bit?
Do I need to install 32-bit version of MinGW? If I do, where can I download it?
But as far as I know, mingw-w64 for win32 and win64, or not?
Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0):

MinGW-w64 exists for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.
My personal build at http://winlibs.com/ provides separate standalone downloads for 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.
Please see the site for instructions on how to use. It also includes instructions on how to configure Code::Blocks IDE to have both compilers available.